# Can't get width of MapCircle before changing zoom

Tags: qt, qml

I need to get width of  MapCircle in my  Map element, because I need to place MapQuickItem above  MapCircle, and I can do it with toCoordinate() function on Map element. But I can't get width of MapCircle before I change zoom, but after what, there is correct number.

I can't get width even when I use mapReady property of Map

```
        onMapReadyChanged: {
            if (mapReady){
                console.log(mapReady+" width = "+testCircle.width)
            }
        }
```

Even though  width and height of rectangle inside MapQuickItem are equal to width of MapCircle.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6

Window {
    width: 1200
    height: 1200
    visible: true

    Plugin {
        id: mapPlugin
        name: "esri" // "mapboxgl", "esri", ...
    }

    Map {
        id: _map
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: mapPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(59.91, 28.6)
        zoomLevel: 9

        Component.onCompleted: {
            console.log("on completed "+testCircle.width)
        }

        MapCircle {
            id: testCircle
            center: parent.center
            radius: 50000.0
            color: '#8000FF00'
            border.width: 3
            border.color: "orange"
        }

        MapQuickItem {
            id: testItem
            coordinate: parent.center

            sourceItem: Rectangle {
                id:testR
                width: testCircle.width
                height: width
                color: "pink"
            }
        }

        onMapReadyChanged: {
            if (mapReady){
                console.log(mapReady+" width = "+testCircle.width)
            }
        }

        onZoomLevelChanged: {
            console.log(" width = "+testCircle.width+" "+testCircle.implicitWidth)
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get right result before changing zoom? Is it possible? Here is console output of this code before zoom

```
qml: on completed 0
qml: true width = 0
```

but after zooming Map there is fine result

```
qml:  width = 658.222013399468 0
qml:  width = 605.3187684634481 0
```

I can't get why I don't receive correct number before zooming, even though when I assign sizes of rectangle in MapQuickItem equal to width of mapCircle, there is correct picture in Map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to place the MapQuickItem on top of the MapCircle it is only necessary to set the appropriate offset:

```
// ...
MapQuickItem {
    id: testItem
    coordinate: parent.center
    sourceItem: Rectangle {
        id:testR
        x: - width/2  // <---
        y: - height/2 // <---
        width: testCircle.width
        height: width
        color: "pink"
    }
}
// ...
```